# Flagged obvious spam post but flag was declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderation

[This question and its two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406584#43406857) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4swl.png)) are blatant spam - nothing here that even pretends to be a programming-related question (apart from the `machine-learning` tag). Yet when I flagged the question as spam I got "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". Furthermore I flagged the two spam answers and those flags were deemed "helpful".

I'm not particularly bothered by this, but it suggests that there might be something in the flag review process that needs improvement, so I thought I'd mention it. I see there have been slightly similar posts in the past, but in those cases the spam doesn't seem to have been quite so blatantly obvious, so human error may have been to blame. I don't see how human error could explain this one though?

Comment: "I don't see how human error could explain this one though?" Probably a misclick. The moderator reflagged the post immediately after declining yours. They probably realized how colossally they messed up.

Comment: Ah, OK - I hadn't thought of "low level" human errors such as mis-clicks - I suppose one can get somewhat "punch drunk" when wading through all this crap. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR: That's okay. "Not thinking of something" is quite human. Consider it human error.

Comment: but the linked question is now gone - how do I study it for further review? :)

Comment: @Adam http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jwoj-U7wtV0J:stackoverflow.com/questions/43406584/how-make-co2-laser-machine-engrave-on-metal+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: @Adam Simple, go get another 9316 rep so you can see deleted posts!

Answer (score 84):

Yup, that was my mistake, I had mis-clicked. Sorry about that.

If it helps, it took all of 26 seconds between me misclicking and the accounts all being nuked.

Comment: No apology necessary - I was just mildly curious. ;-)

Comment: 26 seconds you say ? Let's set a new performance goal and see if we can get that under 20 seconds. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR: it is hard to get a statistically significant series of measurements however; I don't *usually* mis-click. :-)

Comment: Man, Martijn, you're messing up a lot. Maybe you should uncover your fingers and use those? From my experience using hooves on computer mice, it's... difficult to control. Fingers are helpful.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes yeah we want the paper bag :D, to be honest he also handle tons of flags, so I guess the % is more or less the same as others. It's one of those mods, I clear the queue, stand clear, thanks Martijn

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe you just don't usually _notice_ you've mis-clicked :-) :-)

Comment: I'm curious when someone mis-clicks; is there not a JS pop alert with a message asking if they're sure they want to do this? (Since I don't know how all that works on your end). This isn't the first time this happens; am sure and I too have been hit by this a few times.

Comment: step 1: miss click, step 2: answer, step 3: ???, step 4: +72 upvotes

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I process several hundred flags every single day (7.2k in the past month, I'm busy at work so it's been low lately); statistically it is impossible not to make at least *some* mistakes; all of us moderators are humans and humans are not infallible. The trick is to keep the error rate low, and to fix the mistakes you do make. The dialogs look a lot like the ones community moderation uses, just with more options.

Comment: I hear you @MartijnPieters thanks; I now have a much better idea as to what being a moderator involves, *cheers*