# Should bad declined flags be challenged for the sake of reputation?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, profile-page

Having rejected flags surely doesn't help our profile.
So, when a bad declined flag occurs like this [misclick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348164/4625305) by our admin, should the decision be challenged on meta like Bonifacio2 did?

If the bad post remain, I think we should challenge in order to get the post deleted.
 However, when the bad post got deleted anyway, should we challenge anyway for the sake of our profile?

Comment: The question you linked to doesn't contain spam, not in the English portion nor in the (deleted) Persian text. Just because a question mentions that they are using a certain software product, doesn't make it spam.

Comment: There isn't really a 'reputation' to maintain, when it comes to flagging, because the flag decline count *is not public*. Sure, occasional mistakes are made, but that's not something you need to worry about. The wrong flag warning system is quite generous before it eventually blocks you from flagging if you do use the flags wrong (and blocks are never permanent).

Comment: @MartijnPieters You got me, indeed I made a mistake.

Comment: Now, I'm always happy to explain why a flag was declined; it can help for the flagger to understand what, if anything, went wrong, and improve your flagging habits that way. Or to get an explanation from the moderator if we did accidentally got something wrong. But don't worry about your repute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declined flags have no effect on your reputation.  If you have a lot of declined flags, you may get flag-banned, but that's about it.  In all other circumstances, the number of declined flags has no effect on anything. (And, in particular, are not publicly visible.)

If you don't understand why a flag was declined, asking about it on Meta is good practice.  But you don't need to challenge every declined flag if you don't want to do so.  Declined flags can't get un-declined, so this won't affect your profile either way.